# Minesweeper Code error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,m,counter=0;;
cin>>n>>m;
char x[n][m];
int y[n][m];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        cin>>x[i][j];              //array input
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        counter=0;
        if(x[i][j]=='.')                         // searching for mines(*)
        {
            if (x[i][j-1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i][j+1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i-1][j]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i+1][j]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i+1][j-1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i+1][j+1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i-1][j-1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i-1][j+1]=='*')
                counter++;
        }
        if(x[i][j]!='*')
        y[i][j]=counter;                  // assign values
        else
        y[i][j]='*';

    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        if(y[i][j]==42)
            cout<<'*';
        else
        cout<<y[i][j];                // output numeric array 
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

This is Minesweeper code which has input like

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
```

and output

```
*100
2210
1*10
1110
```

But the code's output is

```
*101
2210
1*10
1110
```

the zero on the top right turn into 1 What's making it do that ?

and is there an more easy way to search for the mines(*) without all the if conditions ?

Comment: `char x[n][m];` is not Standard C++ unless `n` and `m` are constant expressions, and should be avoided.

Comment: When you check the right neighbour of that top-right cell, what do you expect to happen? You are also using VLAs which C++ doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading beyond array's memory. While you're on lines 0..n-2, you're reading next line's chars, at line `n-1` you're reading inaccessible memory.

You have to check that memory you access belongs to proper lines and are within array bounds.

I.e.

```
       if (x[i][j+1]=='*')
```

What if `j == m - 1`?

```
       if (x[i-1][j]=='*')
```

What if `i == 0`?

There are basically two fixes to this problem.
First, you can each time check that `i, j` are in bounds, say

```
       if (j < m - 1 && x[i][j+1]=='*')
```

That will solve the problem, but is bad from code reuse perspective. I'd write a function, say

```
char get_at(char ** array, int i, int j, int n, int m)
{
   if (i >= 0 && i < n && j >= 0 && j < m)
      return array[i][j];
   else
      return '!';
}
```

This function returns `'!'` if indices are out of bounds, so it will not be interpreted as a mine.

Comment: then how can I avoid this @Aneri

Comment: So basically the error in my code (I want to know so I won't repeat it in the future ) was that I was checking out of array bounds and the fix was to insure that i,j are in the range of the array @Aneri

Comment: @MostafaMorsy Not only. You were checking within array bounds but outside the intended line. `y[i][m] == y[i+1][0]`, most likely. So you were inside allowed memory but the index was wrong all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to point something out in your code:

```
int main()
{
int n,m,counter=0;;
cin>>n>>m;
char x[n][m];
int y[n][m];

/** 
  * Minesweeper solving has always worked (if followed step-wise) is        
  * scanning the neihbouring 8 cells i.e.    
  * top(left,middle,right),side(left,right), and 
  * bottom(left,middle,right). You probably should try and follow this
  * in your code so that any indexing issues can be avoided
  *
  *
  * BTW - don't forget the corners/edges
  *
  */
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // This is a bit dangerous what if the index is -1?
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++) // Same indexing issue here.
    {
        cin>>x[i][j];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++) 
    {
        counter=0;
        if(x[i][j]=='.') // If current pos is '.'
        {
            if (x[i][j-1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i][j+1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i-1][j]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i+1][j]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i+1][j-1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i+1][j+1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i-1][j-1]=='*')
                counter++;
            if (x[i-1][j+1]=='*')
                counter++;
        }
        if(x[i][j]!='*') // If current pos is ANYTHING but '*', may be you want ELSE_IF condition?
        y[i][j]=counter;
        else
        y[i][j]='*';

    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        if(y[i][j]==42)
            cout<<'*';
        else
        cout<<y[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Is that what you are actually thinking?

Comment: @MostafaMorsy     delete your comment please - it is definitely confusing now!